# Are PowerShell Arrays just .NET Arrays?

Tags: .net, arrays, string, powershell

I am creating an array of string objects in [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) which needs to be passed into an [Xceed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xceed) zip library method which expects a string[], but I get an error everytime. It makes me wonder if the PowerShell array is something other than a .NET array. Here is some code:

```
$string_list = @()
foreach($f in $file_list)
{
    $string_list += $f.FullName
}
[Xceed.Zip.QuickZip]::Zip("C:\new.zip", $true, $false, $false, $string_list)
```

The error I get says "An error occurred while adding files to the zip file." If I hard code in values like this it works:

```
[Xceed.Zip.QuickZip]::Zip("C:\new.zip", $true, $false, $false, "test.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.txt")
```

Can someone help me figure this out? I can't understand what the difference would be...

EDIT: I have tested and confirmed that my $string_list array is composed of System.String objects

Comment: Can you show us the signature of [Xceed.Zip.QuickZip]::Zip(...)?

Comment: void Zip(String zipFileName, bool replaceExistingFiles, bool recursive, bool preservePaths, String[] filesToZip)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you specify:

```
$string_list = @()
```

You have given PowerShell no type info so it creates an array of System.Object which is an array that can hold any object:

```
PS> ,$string_list | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Object[]
```

Try specifying a specific array type (string array) like so:

```
PS> [string[]]$string_list = @()
PS> ,$string_list | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.String[]
```